# window.onlaod js and javaFX

Tags: javascript, javafx, webview

I would like to know if there's a way to get the `window.onload` event after execute `webEngine.executeScript`?

that is to say, 
I have my javaFX code like this :

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                    State oldState = (State) oldValue;
                    State newState = (State) newValue;
                    System.out.printf("%s -> %s", oldValue, newValue).println();

                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");

                        JavaBridge bridge = new JavaBridge();
                        window.setMember("java", bridge);
                        webEngine.executeScript(String.format("fct('%s')", attr.toString()));


                    }

                }

            });



            webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("test.html").toExternalForm());
```

And javascript code  :

```
function f1() {
        alert("window.onload");

    }

function initMap() {


    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center : {
            lat : -34.397,
            lng : 10.644
        },
        zoom : 8
    });

//This does nothing triggers
    map.addDomListener(window, "load", f1);
    window.onload = f1;

}

function fct(attr) {


    var script = document.createElement('script');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + attr
            + "&callback=initMap";


};
```

Any help ?

Comment: AFAIK the onload event will have been called before you get to the point of attaching the listeners. Do you need to use the onload event, or are you experiencing a particular problem?

Comment: I need to know if all the images are loaded after the execution of the js function "fct". Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Do you mean all of the Google Maps API when you say images? You don't seem to be loading images other than those. Check out [link](https://github.com/rterp/GMapsFX) if you're interested in a package set up to use Google Maps, or even just to see how it's being handled. It registers a listener using `google.maps.event.addListener` waiting on the `projection_changed` event to detect when the map is up and running.